# Executing curl request

Tags: php, curl

I'm new with `cURL` and was referring this example : http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php#99979

I wanted to write the following curl request:

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/solr/update/extract?literal.id=doc1&commit=true" -F "myfile=@test.pdf"
```

using the curl predefined constants. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php)

I started off by writing:

```
$tuCurl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8080/solr/update/extract?literal.id=doc1&commit=true");
```

But, after that, I couldn't figure out how to write `-F "myfile=@test.pdf"` part.

Comment: So what is the question that you need help with?

Comment: `CURLOP_POST`, `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, & give the full path to the file (not a relative one).